# Multiple Sensor Interrupt Combine?

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, interrupts

I built an IoT device that sleeps and wake with Texas TPL5111. (Timed wake system with external wakeup option). Also i have external sensors and want to awake system with sensor interrupts. 2 wan on this section.

1. Using I2C multiplexer like PCF8574 (have an int output). Sensor interrupt pins connected to PCF8574 I/O pins. And PCF8574 INT output is used to control TPL5111 shut pin.
2. Using a logic design to combine interrupt pins.

[image: Logic design]

- OR Gate = SN74HCS32 (combining sensor interrupts)
- AND Gate = SN74HCS08 (for enable or disable sensor interrupt)
- NAND Gate = SN74HCS00 (for inverting active low inputs)

Which solution is effective in low power consumption IoT device.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: is there any reason why you could not use a `wired logic` circuit? ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection

Comment: I want to know which sensor has int and i close the int by i2c.

Comment: how long do the interrupt signals last?

Comment: for example a TH sensor. It gives interrupt active high (but some other sensors are active low). interrupt stuck at high as long as i clear it with mcu

Comment: let's say that you have 20 interrupt sources ... you can connect them to a 20 bit shift register ... you can also `wire OR` them to generate a single interrupt signal ... when the interrupt signal becomes active, you use the shift register to determine the actual source of the interrupt